# How can I check if it's a monotonic series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given this series:

$$a_{n} = \sin(3n-9)$$

How can I check if it's a monotonic series or not? (I tried to check if $a_{n} \geq a_{n+1}$ or $a_{n} \leq a_{n+1}$ but I can not prove it that way)

Comment: try $n=3,4,5$ if working in radians or $n=3,33,63$ if working in degrees

Comment: I would guess that the set of values assumed by all members of the sequence is dense in $[-1,1]$, so certainly not monotonic

Comment: You're right: it *is* dense in $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that $-1$ $\le$ $\sin x$ $\le$ $1$, and $\sin x$ is strictly alternating, your intuition should tell you it is not monotonous on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

To prove $\sin x$ is not monotonous on $\mathbb{R}$, you must show that at no point is it constantly increasing there onwards, or constantly decreasing there onwards. So if you show that it constantly decreases AND decreases then you have your proof. One way to prove that is:

Show that $\sin x$ takes a certain value "$a$" periodically (every $k$ moves down the $x-axis$)$\,$ AND$\,$ Show that $\sin x$ takes a certain value "$b$" periodically (every $k$ moves down the $x-axis$).

Let $a=1$ and $b=-1$

$\sin (3n-9)=-1$ and $\sin (3n-9)=1$. We know that $x=3\pi/2+2k\pi$ when $\sin x=-1$ and that $x=\pi/2+2k\pi$ when $\sin x=1$

So $\sin (3n-9)=1$ when $n=\pi/6+2k\pi/3+3$ and $\sin (3n-9)=-1$ when $n=\pi/2+2k\pi/3+3$ for all $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Having shown that two different points are constantly re-intersected every $k$ times implies that an increase is always followed by a deacrease every $k$ times. So $\sin (3n-9)$ is not monotonous.

Comment: n is generally taken to represent an integer.

Comment: You are right, my bad, I guess it can still be useful to know. But in that case, I would just use that Limsup and Liminf are different therefore $\sin x$ is alternating, therefore non-monotonous.